# The largest set $\bar{\mathcal{E}}$ of Epis, stable under composition, such that every mono in $\bar{\mathcal{E}}$ is iso

Tags: category-theory

Let $\mathcal A$ be a category and $\bar{\mathcal{E}}$ be the largest subset of all Epis, stable under composition, such that every mono in $\bar{\mathcal{E}}$  is iso.

> What is known about $\bar{\mathcal{E}}$?

Obviously every strong epi is in $\bar{\mathcal{E}}$ (assuming these are actually epi). What can be said about the converse, is there a counterexample?

If so, do the elements of $\bar{\mathcal{E}}$ have a name? Are there any other known properties or characterizations in certain kinds of categories?

Comment: This seems vaguely related to the notion of an _extremal monomorphism_ $Mono^\epsilon$, i.e. an $m$ such that whenever $m=kp$ with $p$ an epi, then $p$ is an iso. Finite co/completeness of $\cal A$ entails that $(Epi, Mono^\epsilon)$ is a factorization system on $\cal A$, and sometimes $Mono^\epsilon = Mono$; this is the greatest of all _proper_ FS on $\cal A$.

Comment: Could you elaborate one that "greatest" part? In the presence of finite limits strong epis coincide with extremal ones.

Comment: Greatest only means that it is the largest :)

Comment: @FoscoLoregian When is factorization system larger than another? And I also meant: I probably have no clue how to prove that.

Comment: Since $g\circ f$ mono implies $f$ mono, then whenever $f$ is epic and $g\circ f$ is a a monic epic, $f$ is also a monic epic. Consequently, the class of all epics that are not monic epics without being isos is already closed under composition. Hence, your question is the complement of characterizing monic epics (sometimes called *bimorphisms*) among epics.

Comment: @VladimirSotirov I'm probably missing something obvious. According to your first sentence we know that $f \in \bar{\mathcal{E}}$ is iso. But why is $g\circ f$ iso?

Comment: If $f$ is iso, then $g\in\bar{\mathcal E}$ implies $g\circ f\in\bar{\mathcal E}$ because whether a morphism is monic, epic, or iso is preserved by pre- (and post-)composition with isomorphisms.

Comment: @VladimirSotirov Ah, okay. You should post this as an answer so that I can accept it.